# Error publishing my Asp.net application to Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure

When I'm trying to publish my asp.net application I got this error.

Publish has encountered an error.
Build failed. Check the output window for more details.

The error in the output window :

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Web deployment task failed. (Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'https://fadel.scm.azurewebsites.net/msdeploy.axd?site=fadel'.)
>   This error indicates that you cannot connect to the server. Make sure the service URL is correct, firewall and network settings on this computer and on the server computer are configured properly, and the appropriate services have been started on the server.
>   Error details:
>   Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'https://fadel.scm.azurewebsites.net/msdeploy.axd?site=fadel'.
>   The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
>   Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>   An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host   Delivery        0

Here is the error log file

> 25/01/2019 18:59:20 System.AggregateException: One or more errors
>   occurred. ---> System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window
>   for more details.    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish.PublishService.VsWebProjectPublish.<>c__DisplayClass43_0.b__2()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.d__127.MoveNext()
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.<---

Comment: are there any details in the Output window? Does the application build without trying to deploy?

Comment: @Rikalous 'This error indicates that you cannot connect to the server. Make sure the service URL is correct, firewall and network settings on this computer and on the server computer are configured properly, and the appropriate services have been started on the server.
'

Comment: Looks like a network issue unfortunately.

Comment: @Rikalous But any other application working good.

Comment: can you ping fadel.azurewebsites.net ?